# Why is this angularjs ui-router code crashing my browser?

Tags: angularjs, service, angular-ui-router, components

This is my controller. By now, for testing purposes, I just want to output "TEST" in my browser (not only in the console)

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('data')
.controller('MainMenuAppController', MainMenuAppController);

MainMenuAppController.$inject = ['MenuDataService', 'items'];
function MainMenuAppController(MenuDataService, items) {
  var mainList = this;
  mainList.items ='TEST'; console.log(mainList.items);
}

})();
```

Here the component:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('data')
.component('cat', {
  templateUrl: 'src/menuapp/templates/template.html',
  bindings: {
    items: '<'
  }
});

})();
```

The template:

```
<cat items="mainList.items"></cat>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

The service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('data')
    .service('MenuDataService', MenuDataService);

    MenuDataService.$inject = ['$http','$q', '$timeout']
    function MenuDataService($http,$q, $timeout) {
        var service = this;
        var items = [];

        service.getItemsForCategory = function (shortName) {
            var response = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: (ApiBasePath + "/menu_items.json"),
                params: {
                    category: shortName
                }
            });

            return response;
        };


        service.getAllCategories = function () {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get( "http://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/categories.json")
            .success(function(data) {
                service.items = data;
                // Wait 2 seconds before returning
                $timeout(function () {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    }, 400);
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject("Failed to get categories");
            });
            //console.log(deferred.promise);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }

})();
```

The module:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('data', ['ui.router']);

})();
```

Routes

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('data')
.config(RoutesConfig);

RoutesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function RoutesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Redirect to home page if no other URL matches
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  // *** Set up UI states ***
  $stateProvider

  // Home page
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'src/menuapp/templates/home.template.html'
  })

  // Categories
  .state('mainList', {
    url: '/main-list',
    templateUrl: 'src/menuapp/templates/template.html',
    controller: 'MainMenuAppController as mainList',
    resolve: {
      items: ['MenuDataService', function (MenuDataService) { 
        return MenuDataService.getAllCategories();
      }]
    }     
  })


}

})();
```

Well, this is showing 'TEST' in the console but not in the browser and in a few seconds the browser crashes with no explanation.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your cat component may have an infinite recursion.

Comment: It looks like it. But how can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, the template

```
<cat items="mainList.items"></cat>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

is the template for your `cat`-component.

If that is the case, this causes an infinite recursion of nested cat components, which is the most likely cause for your browser to crash. Basically the above results in the following being generated for all eternity (or well, until the browser crashes).

```
<cat items="mainList.items">
    <cat items="mainList.items">
        <cat items="mainList.items">
            <cat items="mainList.items">
                <cat items="mainList.items">
                ... repeated forever
                </cat>
                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </cat>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </cat>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </cat>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</cat>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

To fix it, you simply need to not use the `<cat>` component inside the template for your `cat` component - unless they're supposed to be nested, in which case you need to have some way to stop the recursion once it's reached the expected nesting level.